# What is correct- 'Its apps' or 'its own apps'?

Tags: word-choice

I read this [article](http://www.engadget.com/2015/09/18/samsung-galaxy-tab-s2-review/). I found the following line in it:

> At this point, I wonder why Samsung even bothers including ***its own apps*** when there are so many better alternatives out there.

Can I write the above sentence as following without changing its meaning?

> At this point, I wonder why Samsung even bothers including ***its apps*** when there are so many better alternatives out there.

IMO, in 'its own premises', 'own' looks redundant. But then, I have read "Enter at your own risk" as well.

SO, my questions are: Can we write 'its own', 'your own', etc.? Doesn't 'own' show redundancy in the above-mentioned sentence? Are there any specific rules for using 'own'?

Comment: This may seem like a simple question, but a simple question like this is not easy to answer. Those who know, know. Those who don't, do not. How can we help someone who doesn't know to know, that's what I usually think when reading posts on ELL. I don't have a "right" answer at the moment, but I think the sense of emphasis, though definitely there, is not enough on its own. How is *own* different from other emphasizing words (like *very*, *that*, *too*, etc.)? A sketch of my answer would be, it emphasizes the sense of its/yours/mine/his and it's its/yours/mine/his alone, and no one's else.

Comment: Also see: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/own_1. *Someone's very own* is also common enough.

Comment: As it happens, I've recently come into possession of a Samsung SCX-3400 laser printer which insisted on installing "its own" print manager app. Noting the absolutely outrageous price for a (relatively low capacity) replacement toner cartridge, my guess is the reason they want users to run their app is so they can quietly update the printer's firmware as and when required. Not so much to implement new features beneficial to the user. They just want to be able to ensure the printer recognizes and refuses to accept each new 3rd-party cartridge as and when they appear on the market.

Answer (score 3):

Correct? Both are correct!

**BUT**

'Its own apps' conveys the message in a better way. We use 'own' to emphasize the matter. In this sentence, it's said that though there are many applications already available, the author wonders that why Samsung even bothers including its ***own*** apps.

Take another example:

> When you have a public phone to use for free, why use ***your own*** phone?

Now here, I don't need emphasizing. So, I won't use *your own*. Say--

> Your phone is ringing, pick it up.